# Starting another windows service and closing it from the API level after starting and closing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi

I have a problem. From the API level, I have to start the windows service (different) and stop it after closing the API. While starting it won't be a big problem for me because I would like to use the ServiceController class to check whether the service has the appropriate status, I don't really know how to do it when closing the application in NET 6.0

My code :

```
var webApplicationOptions = new WebApplicationOptions
{
  ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory,
  Args = args,
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
builder.Host.UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory);
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

ServiceController rabbitService = new ServiceController(builder.Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQServiceName").Value);
if (rabbitService.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
  rabbitService.Start();
```